# Does there exist a subfield $S$ of $\mathbb C$ such that $\mathbb R \subset S \subset \mathbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Does there exist a subfield $S$ of $\mathbb C$ such that $\mathbb R \subset S \subset \mathbb C$ ? ; I kind of have a feeling that there does not exist any such $S$ but cannot prove . Thanks  in advance for any help.

Comment: That wouldn't be a subfield of $\mathbb R$ if $\mathbb R\subsetneq S$. Extension field of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sorry , edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is a field, $\mathbb R\subsetneq S\subseteq\mathbb C$. Choose $z\in S\setminus\mathbb R$. Then $z=a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R,\,b\ne0$, and $i=\frac{z-a}b\in S$, whence $S=\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 7):

If $S$ is a field such that $\mathbb R\subseteq S\subseteq \mathbb C$, then $S$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ which is a subspace of a vector space of dimension $2$, $\mathbb C$. This means that $S=\mathbb R$ or $S=\mathbb C$.

Comment: but only as a vector space $i\mathbb R$ also has dimension $1$ over $\mathbb R$ ... where are we using the fact subfiled of $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: In the fact that the maximal dimension can be $2$. We know that $\mahbb R$ is in $S$. So $S$ can't be $i\mathbb R$.

Comment: I see , you mean since $1$ is a non-zero vector in $S$ so dimension of $S$ is $1$ means $S=$span$\{1\}$

Comment: Off-course $1$ is not a vector space , when did I say that ? I said $\{1\}$ is the spanning set

Comment: Yeah, reading failure on my part.

Comment: Tha argument I'm making is very simple. If $V\subseteq S\subseteq W$ are vector spaces over a field, $k$, and $V$ is dimension $1$ and $W$ is dimension $2$, then $S=V$ or $S=W$.